# What is the function of "west" in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs

Little House on the Prairie contains the following sentence:
"Santa Claus had the longest, thickest, whitest set of whiskers west of the Mississippi."

Is "west" acting as an adverb that modifies "had"?

Comment: Are you trying to understand the meaning of the sentence, or analyze the grammar?

Comment: Do you really think I don't understand the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: I don't know -- sometimes I guess wrong. Many people who ask questions here are non-native speakers with limited understanding of the meanings of common constructions.

Comment: Non-native speaker or not, I'm not sure what part of the topic sentence or the post itself indicates that I don't understand the meaning of the sentence. I'm being pretty specific about wanting to know something about the grammatical function of "west", not its meaning.

Comment: Nothing in the question or your comments indicates you don't understand the meaning of the sentence, but neither is there clear confirmation that you do understand it. I've certainly seen questions here where somebody asked about a specific grammar thing but then it turned out their understanding of the meaning was wrong - note I'm not saying that's the case here, I think you do understand, I'm just adding to Mike's explanation of why it's not unreasonable to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more explicit I could have been about the kind of information I was trying to obtain. Asking how something functions is quite a bit different from asking what something means. Which is to say, even if I didn't understand the meaning of the sentence, how exactly would an explanation of the meaning of the sentence have clarified whether west is an adverb or not??

Answer (score 1):

"West" modifies "**set**". Which "set"? The "set west of the Mississippi".

Comment: Ah, OK. So it's functioning as an adjective modifying "set"?

Comment: The sentence is describing **a** set of whiskers, not **the** set of whiskers. There are other sets West of the Mississippi.

Comment: @nnnnnn There are other sets West of the Mississippi. But Santa has  the (longest / thickest / whitest / west of the Mississippi) set.

Comment: @TFlo83 yes. an adjective. It would also be correct to add "that were" before "west" to create the adjective clause "... set of whiskers that were west of the Mississippi." And, then the antecedent for "that" is "set".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: It can be easier to see these non-obvious constructions if one uses simplified examples (of course, one has to get the correct adjusted version). 'the tallest building west of the Mississippi ...' ... 'the tallest western building'. So in the simpler example, 'western' is an adjective modifying 'building', and we are talking about the tallest member of the set [of] {_western_ buildings}. // ... the _longest, thickest **and** whitest(!)_ member of the set [of] {sets of whiskers [existing] _west of the Mississippi_}. 'west of the Mississippi' is best seen as an adjectival phrase (adjective + ...

Comment: complement, if one insists on further deconstruction), which is placed postnominally unlike most single-word adjectives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Consider, perhaps, a longer *whiz*-deletion: *the whitest whiskers **that were to the** west of the Mississippi*. Now what do you make of *west* in that construction? Could this be an NP used as an adverbial?

Comment: @tchrist Yes; I can't see that as an invalid argument. But I'll stick with my opinion that this is _better_ seen as an adjectival, as user 312 says used as an identifier. // These relicts _usually_ have single words doing duty for shrivelled longer strings, and defying trad POS-tagging. Innit.